# Stream elasticsearch data to kafka

Tags: elasticsearch-plugin, confluent-kafka-python

I have a requirement to stream the data from Elasticsearch to Kafka. I'm looking at a any connectors between Elasticsearch and Kafka (Python implementation) that could either automatically identified CDC and streams the data to kafka or i can implement my own CDC approach but looking for a robust way to ES - kafka connector. Please share any ready made solutions or thoughts on this!
I'm going through Elasticsearch sink connector between Kafka and ES, but it is not evidant whether its bi-directional (Kafka <-> ES).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think [Debezium](https://debezium.io) has an ElasticSearch source connector but you *could* write your own.
Another project I just came across for my own CDC/ETL needs is Airbyte. They *do* have an ElasticSearch source: https://docs.airbyte.com/integrations/sources/elasticsearch. I just stumbled upon them last night so I can't speak for their product.